# Unable to change button UI on AJAX getJSON .done

Tags: ajax, pdo

After creating `add post to favorite` and posted at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/238164/62236) i had to improve my code as bellow,
 And after changing code the button UI doesn't change when clicked

**post_page.php**

```
<?php
$email = 'user@mail.com';
// Query to get the user_id
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT memberID FROM members WHERE email = :email AND active="Yes" ');
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$mbid = $row['memberID'];

$pid = '4';
// Query to Get the Director ID
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE id =:id');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $pid));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {

    echo "<p>Director: " . $row['tit'] . "</p> ";
    $fav_image = checkFavorite($mbid, $pid, $conn);
    echo "Favorite? : " . $fav_image . "";
}

function checkFavorite($mbid, $pid, $conn) {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE memberID=:mid AND id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':mid' => $mbid, ':id' => $pid));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count == 0) {
    echo "<div class='button btn btn-block btn-outline-danger' method='Like'  data-user=" . $mbid . " data-post=" . $pid . "> Add<i class='mi mi_sml ml-2' id=" . $pid . ">favorite_border</i></div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='button btn btn-block btn-outline-danger' method='Unlike'  data-user=" . $mbid . " data-post=" . $pid . ">Remove<i class='mi mi_sml ml-2' id=" . $pid . ">favorite</i></div>";
}
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.getJSON('favs.php',
                        {user_id: $(this).attr('data-user'),
                            director_id: $(this).attr('data-post'),
                            method: $(this).attr('method')})
                        .done(function (json) {
                            switch (json.feedback) {
                                case 'Like'   :
                                    $(this).attr('method', 'Unlike');
                                    $(this).html('<i class="mi mi_sml text-danger" id="' + json.id + '">favorite</i>Remove Favorite').toggleClass('button mybtn'); // Replace the image with the liked button
                                    break;
                                case 'Unlike' :
                                    $(this).html('<i class="mi mi_sml" id="' + json.id + '">favorite_border</i>Add Favorite').toggleClass('mybtn button');
                                    $(this).attr('method', 'Like');
                                    break;
                                case 'Fail'   :
                                    alert('The Favorite setting could not be changed.');
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                            alert("Error Changing Favorite: " + error);
                        });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**favs.php**

```
<?php

include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/include/config.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/classes/function.php");

$method = clean_input($_GET['method']);
$user_id = clean_input($_GET['user_id']);
$director_id = clean_input($_GET['director_id']);

switch ($method) {
    case "Like" :
        $query = 'INSERT INTO favorite (memberID, id) VALUES (:mID, :pID)';
        break;
    case "Unlike" :
        $query = 'DELETE FROM favorite WHERE memberID=:mID and id=:pID';
        break;
}
$feedback = 'Fail'; // start with pessimistic feedback
if (isset($query)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mID', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 12);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pID', $director_id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 12);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $feedback = $method;
    } // feedback becomes method on success
}
echo json_encode(['id' => $director_id,
    'feedback' => $feedback]);
?>
```

> My problem is when button is clicked and when ajax return success the button should change its UI.
>   where else in my case its not changing when on page load it show `Add` even after clicking on button and ajax return **success** still it is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is `$(this)` i.e: In ajax success function jquery is not able to find which element is clicked and where to apply required changes. To solve this you can store `$(this)` in some variable and use the same. Like below :

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
  //getting current element which is clicked
  var button = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getJSON('favs.php', {
      user_id: $(this).attr('data-user'),
      director_id: $(this).attr('data-post'),
      method: $(this).attr('method')
    })
    .done(function(json) {
      switch (json.feedback) {
        case 'Like':
          button.attr('method', 'Unlike');
          button.html('<i class="mi mi_sml text-danger" id="' + json.id + '">favorite</i>Remove Favorite').toggleClass('button mybtn'); // Replace the image with the liked button
          break;
        case 'Unlike':
          button.html('<i class="mi mi_sml" id="' + json.id + '">favorite_border</i>Add Favorite').toggleClass('mybtn button');
          button.attr('method', 'Like');
          break;
        case 'Fail':
          alert('The Favorite setting could not be changed.');
          break;
      }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      alert("Error Changing Favorite: " + error);
    });
});
```