# Populate <select> on click using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a `<select>` with only one option, i want to get the rest of the options from a database using PHP and then populate said `<select>` with the PHP result using AJAX.

Unfortunately my code is not working, im not surprised as im new to both AJAX and jQuery but i dont get any errors to guide myself through the issue.

The PHP works as expected because its used in another part of the site and i have no issues with it so my error must be in the AJAX (no big surprise here).

Below my HTML:

```
<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="producto" name="producto" required>
    <option disabled selected value>Elegir...</option>
</select>
```

Below my AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#producto").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch_lista_productos_compra.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#producto").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Below my PHP code:

```
<?php 

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testground/php/db_key.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE disponibilidad = 'disponible'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    echo <<<EOT
    <option value="$titulo">$titulo</option>\n
EOT;
}
?>
```

As always any kind of help is greatly appreacited and thanks for your time.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

`<select>` has a duplicated id, perhaps i should i have stated this from the start as i know think thats whats causing my issue.

The fact is that in this `<form>` the selects are created dynamically on user request. They click on *Add product* and a new select with the products avaiable is created, i know the id/name of said input must have **[ ]** (`id="producto[]"`) for it to be converted into an array but i dont know how to make the AJAX deal with this *dynamically created reapeated selects issue*. I apologise for this belated aclaration i realise now it is of the utmost importance.

Comment: May be using `class` instead of `id` and when you need to add new options via ajax , use `$(this)` to add to the particular select only ?

Comment: Great suggestions @Swati sadly it didnt work, perhaps im not using the `this` selector properly, i pasted the updated version of the script on pastebin for the sake of keeping this comment readable. Check it out please, https://pastebin.com/raw/rtXz8BkZ .

Comment: put `var ele=$(this);` out of your `ajax` call and write `ele.append(data);` under your success function it should work. Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60759728/10606400) answer.

Comment: It didnt work either, here's another pastebin with the code updated for you to check i did things exactly as you intended. https://pastebin.com/raw/HTjrPCrD

Comment: does your console shows any errors? does proper data is coming from ajax call ? because, i didn't find any error in ajax call .

Comment: **[EDIT TO MY EARLIER COMMENT]** I put a `console.log(data)` in the `success` to see if the values from the `.php` where being retrieved correctly and it didnt work either. Perhaps the function it self is not being triggered at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210483/discussion-between-swati-and-minnen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the code in the question was actually working properly, the problem was not the code itself but the fact that, as i stated (sadly on a later edit and not right from the start) in the question, there where more than one `<select>` using the same id, therefore everytime the AJAX was executed the result was appended to the first `<select>` only, and it was appended over and over again everytime i clicked it, **my solution was unifiying both the AJAX that populated the `<select>` and the jQuery that created the said dynamic `<select>`'s all in one script** thus solving all of my issues at once.

Below my jQuery/AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10;
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");
        var x = 0;
        $(add_button).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/testground/php/fetch_lista_productos_compra.php',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(x < max_fields) {
                        x++;
                        var html = '';
                        html += '<div class="form-group row" id="inputFormRow" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">';
                        html += '<label class="col-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Producto</label>';
                        html += '<div class="col-7">';
                        html += '<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="producto" name="producto[]" required>';
                        html += '<option disabled selected value>Elegir...</option>';
                        html += data;
                        html += '</select>';
                        html += '</div>';
                        html += '<div class="col-1 my-auto" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">';
                        html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>';
                        html += '</div>';
                        html += '</div>';
                        $(wrapper).append(html);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
            $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove(); x--;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to thank everyone that took the time to help me out with this **Swati**, **Serghei Leonenco** and **Scaramouche**, this community is truly amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit your response from this:

```
<?php 

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testground/php/db_key.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE disponibilidad = 'disponible'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    echo <<<EOT
    <option value="$titulo">$titulo</option>\n
EOT;
}
?>
```

**To this:**

```
    <?php 

    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testground/php/db_key.php';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE disponibilidad = 'disponible'");

    $response = '';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
        $titulo = $row['titulo'];
        $response .= '<option value="' .$titulo . '">' . $titulo . '</option>'; //Concatenate your response
    }

    echo $response;

?>
```

But i suggest to use `JSON` to get a response and parse it on client side.
You can do this by pushing all values in to response array and use `json_encode()`. At the end you get straight response from the server with just a values, and append thous values whatever you need on client side.

**Update**
Also you append data to your existing `select` options. You can just add thous by editing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select#producto").focus(function() { //Change to on Focus event
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch_lista_productos_compra.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("select#producto").html(data); //Change all html inside the select tag 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Test result:

```js
$('select#options').focus(function(){
    alert("Hello this is a select trigger");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't construct your html on the server, try to just send the raw data and then construct the html client-side, it's better that way and it leaves room for changing the view later without much coupling.

That said, instead of doing:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    echo <<<EOT
    <option value="$titulo">$titulo</option>\n
EOT;
}
```

just do

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

//this is your best bet when sending data from PHP to JS,
//it sends the rows as JSON-like string,
//which you'll parse to an array in the client
echo json_encode($rows);
```

then in the client

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch_lista_productos_compra.php',
    type: 'get',
    success: (data /*json-like string*/) => {
        const dataAsArray = JSON.parse(data);

        $.each(dataAsArray, (index, row) => {
             //now HERE you construct your html structure, which is so much easier using jQuery
            let option = $('<option>');
            option.val(row.titulo).text(row.titulo);
            $("#producto").append(option);
        });
    }
});
```

Regarding your edit about several `select`s

I don't have access to your server of course so I'm using a mock service that returns JSON. IDs are dynamically generated and all data loading occurs asynchronously after you click on the button.
Try using your url and modify the *success* function according to your html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(() => {
      //how many so far...?
      let selectCount = $('select.producto').length;
      
      const select = $('<select class="producto">');
      select.attr('id', `producto${selectCount + 1}`);
      
      //then we fetch from the server and populate select
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
          data.forEach((d) => {
            const option = $('<option>');
            option.val(d.id).text(d.title);
            select.append(option);
          });
        }
      });
      
      document.body.appendChild(select[0]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add'>Add product</button><br>
<!--<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="producto" name="producto" required>
    <option disabled selected value>Elegir...</option>
</select>-->
```

HIH

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#producto").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch_lista_productos_compra.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
               console.log(data)
// $("#producto").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>`enter code here`

try run this and check in your console that weather you are receiving the data from your php or not.
```

Comment: You changed the **$("#producto").click** for **$("#producto").change** and unfortunately it cant be any other thing than .click, plus im not 100% sure but i think it wont be possible to trigger the function with your suggestion as the **<select>** has no options other than the **disabled** one, in any case i did try console.log and the data is getting fetch correctly.